# Sql query to find the row having max sum for a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following 'Scores' table which has score of players in a specific year

```
        Sid    Name     Score     Year
         1     John     500      2016
         2     Kim      900      2015
         3     Ren      300      2016
         4     John     600      2015
         5     Kim      200      2016     
         6     Ren      200      2016
```

Find the player who has scored maximum runs in 2016

I can find this using the below query

```
Select   Name 
  from
     ( select Name
            , sum(Score) as sumScore 
         from Scores 
       where year=2016 
       group
         by Name
     ) sub 
  order 
    by sumScore desc 
 limit 1;
```

**Ouput:**
Ren

How can i find the same without using order by?

I tried below but it doesn't work as it can't refer sub in 2nd where clause and complains relation sub doesn't exist

```
select Name from(select Name,sum(Score) as sumScore from Scores 
where year=2016 group by Name)sub where sumScore=(select max(sumScore) from sub)
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple method uses window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, max(s.score) over (partition by year) as max_score
      from scores s
      where year = 2016
     ) s
where score = max_score;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using correlated subquery

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a6383f5b7ee74446e588c381d676d539)

```
select * from tablename a where score in 
(select max(score) from tablename b where a.year=b.year and b.year=2016)
and a.year=2016
```

OR you can use window function row_number() like below

```
select * from 
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by yr order by score desc) as rn from cte1 
)a where rn=1 and yr=2016
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  name    score   yr
1   John    500    2016
```

Comment: I updated the question with output ,the query in question results in player who has most aggregate score ,where as this would give the player who has max score

Comment: in your example data both ren and john scored 500 after aggregation for year 2016, so in that case what is logic for picking Ren @user3580455

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Scores.Name, SUM(Scores.Score)
FROM (
      select Name,sum(Score) as sumScore, Years 
      from Scores 
      where Years=2016 
      group by Name, Years
     )sub INNER JOIN Scores ON sub.Name = Scores.Name
GROUP BY Scores.Name
HAVING SUM(Scores.Score) = MAX(sub.sumScore)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) in combination with [dense rank](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html)

```
with cte as (
    select *, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score desc, year) rank 
    from demo 
    where year = 2016
)
select * 
from cte 
where rank = 1
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/UVJWZ40863)

Edit to get players with max score of 2016 you can tweak above query as

```
with cte as (
    select name,year ,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sum(score) desc, year) rank 
    from demo 
    where year = 2016
    group by name,year
)
select * 
from cte 
where rank = 1
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/XUNMBK18363)

Comment: Why would you use a CTE? Once you've introduced window functions, you've already solved the problem. The CTE is just overcomplicating things.